# Function as a parameter to an another function in JS?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I try to do something like this [Javascript function as a parameter to another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824393/javascript-function-as-a-parameter-to-another-function), but unfortunately I haven't succeeded. I've done something wrong, but I don't know what. Please help me!

There is a div-element and a function. What the function does is: takes an another function as a parameter and execute it on click on the div-element:

UPDATE3:
I've tried to get the code to work with your examples beneath, with my original web project. But I've got some problem with some parameters. I hope you can answer this question as fast as the others.

UPDATE4:
Thanks Andy E! and all other who have helped me! Really appreciate it!

```
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
  <head>

    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='divElement'>Hello World!</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        function button(exefunction){
            //Some code that decide which date
            var date = '20101010';
            document.getElementById('divElement').onclick = exefunction(date);
        }
        function testfunction(text){
            document.getElementById('divElement').innerHTML = text;
        }
        button(testfunction);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider updating your DOCTYPE.

Comment: What shall I use instead? My IDE doesn't work with HTML-5 doctype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change `testfunction` to `function` and you'll have an anonymous function that is passed as the argument.  You also need to remove the parens from `exefunction` (with them the function is called instead of assigned):

```
    function button(exefunction){
        document.getElementById('divElement').onclick = exefunction;
    }
    button(function(){
        document.getElementById('divElement').innerHTML = 'Changed';
    });
```

[Here is a working example to play around with.](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/gEuYN/)

---

Remove your parens!

```
    button(testfunction);
    // not button(testfunction());
```

The brackets execute the function instead of passing it as an argument.  When you execute a function its return value is passed instead.

[Second working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/gEuYN/1/)

---

For your last edit, you need to create *another* anonymous function for the code to work:

```
        document.getElementById('divElement').onclick = function () {
            exefunction(date);
        }
```

[Third (final?) working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/gEuYN/2/)

Comment: I've already tested to exclude the paranthesis and it doesn't work.

Comment: No need to search for the element twice... You can just write `this.innerHTML`

Comment: I want that new script to work. What have I done wrong this time?

Comment: `button(testfunction());` -> when you append () at the function name, you CALL the function and pass it's return value. Use `button(testfunction);` , you'll pass the function itself.

Comment: 've tried to get the code to work with your examples, with my original web project. But I've got some problem with some parameters. Pls take a look at the updated question

Comment: Yes! Andy E. This will be my last hopefully!

Answer (score 2):

I would replace the line

```
button(testfunction());
```

by

```
button(testfunction);
```

UPDATED
The point is that onclick expect an none argument functions yous should try something along the lines

```
 function button(exefunction){
        //Some code that decide which date
        var date = '20101010';
        document.getElementById('divElement').onclick = function() {exefunction(date);}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! this was maybe to easy question for you guys. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I've tried to get the code to work with your examples, with my original web project. But I've got some problem with some parameters. Pls take a look at the updated question